# Can Cordova be used for web app to mobile native migration?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-3

I have an SPA application that is also customized for mobile browsers. The technology used is Angular 2 and Node. Can I make use of Cordova to wrap and deploy it as a native app onto Android and iOS?

Are there any references?

Comment: There is some tutorial  on internet for that. You can eventually look at ionic.

Comment: Thanks that helps. The right answer would be IONIC 2 + Angular (2/4) should be researched. I am not sure why negative rating for this question. If some one is not interested in the question can't you just leave ? This is a very valid question for a developer who wonders how to make his app compatible with all devices.

Comment: Question does not seem too broad to me. Seems to be an appropriate question.  
Yes, you can refit an Angular2 SPA app into Cordova (Ionic is not necessary).  I assume your use of Node is server-side, and that would remain there, not in the cordova app.  Your cordova app will make ajax calls to your node services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search about ionic 2 which come with angular 2 or ionic 3 which come with angular 4.

Comment: Ionic is not necessary, especially for only refitting an SPA application to a Cordova app.